# Загадка замыканий

Tags: замыкания, javascript

При нажатии на кнопку div.help (height=0) "выезжает" вниз, при нажатии на ту же кнопку - сворачивается. Я решил объединить все это в одном цикле. Что ж, див выезжает, но при клике опять выезжает с начальной позиции! Почему-то в замыкании высота не сохраняется, а принимает начальное значение.
Вот:

```
    someButton.onclick = showHelp;
    var display = document.getElementsByClassName("help")[0];
    var height = 0; // начальное значение 0, такое же прописано и в css
    function showHelp(){    
            // делаем хитрость: изначально h1=0, h2=150, step=1,
            // при повторном клике значения меняются! - h1=150, h2=0, step=-1
            // цикл в каждом из случаев то наращивается до 150, то снова опускается до 0
        var h1,h2,step;
        h1 = height;
        h2 = height = Math.abs(height*1 - 150);
        step = (h2-h1)/Math.abs(h2-h1);
        console.log(h1,h2,step); // проверяем. Действительно это работает
        for (i = h1; i != h2 ;  i = i + step){
            (function(){
                var ii = i;// замыкаем значение каждого из i
                setTimeout(function(){
                    display.style.height = ii + "px";
                },(ii+1)*5);

            })();
        }
    }
```

Все почти идеально. Замыкание работает правильно. ii принимает значения то от 0 до 150, то от 150 до 0. Однако display.style.height почему-то каждый раз увеличивается от 0 до 150, и все. 
Может быть, я какую-то мелочь упустил? Ничего не понимаю. Ведь style.height не может быть каким-то локальным свойством...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все из-за времени в `setTimeout(...,(ii+1)*5);`, оно у Вас зависит от значения ii и даже при обратном порядке определения, сам порядок вызовов не поменяется. В данном случае от перестановки мест итог не меняется, эти два вызова дадут одинаковый результат:

```
//Вызов 1
function(){ display.style.height = 150 + "px"; },(150+1)*5)
...
function(){ display.style.height = 1 + "px"; },(1+1)*5)

//Вызов 2
function(){ display.style.height = 1 + "px"; },(1+1)*5)
...
function(){ display.style.height = 150 + "px"; },(150+1)*5)
```

Надо менять порядок, ну на вскидку:

```
        ...
        j = 0;
        for (i = h1; i != h2 ;  i = i + step){
            j++;
            (function(){
                var ii = i;// замыкаем значение каждого из i
                setTimeout(function(){
                    display.style.height = ii + "px";
                    console.log((ii+1)*5);
                },(j+1)*5);
            })();
        }
        ...
```

И все заработает как надо.

Comment: @Alex Krass, я так и знал, что какая-то невидимая мелочь... Спасибо! Скажите, в таких случаях уместнее ли использовать setInterval?

Comment: @Deus, так навскидку не скажу, можно ли тут удачно прикрутить setInterval.